# How to update multiple records with API?

Tags: api

For doing updates to multiple contacts using the API, is there a better way than this?

```
$res = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', $params);
foreach ($res['values'] as $contact) {
  civicrm_api3('Contact', 'create', array('id' => $contact['id'], ... ))
}
```

For a large number of contacts, this is slow and eventually runs out of memory.

Answer (score 2):

You can use chaining:

```
civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', array(
  'return' => 'id', // more efficient since you don't care about the get results
  ... other search params ...
  'api.Contact.create' => array('last_name' => 'Something'),
));
```

The 'id' will be set for you automatically by the chaining. For more about chaining see [this post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17905/what-is-the-join-logic-when-using-api-chaining-with-action-get).

Also remember the 'gotcha' that unless you specify otherwise, this will only fetch & update 25 records.